# Socket.io disconnects every 5 minutes

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

In Chrome, Socket IO seems to stop transmitting data. Is there an internal reason for this?

I've tried a very simple client and simple server side but consistently the server stops receiving any emits after 5 minute, will then reconnect and it's fine for another 5 minutes.

On top of the internal ping mechanism I have a polling mechanism which sends back session data every 20 seconds.

Comment: Possible firewall or router that is not allowing connection to stay open?  Or possible sleep mode in some computer.

Comment: @jfriend00 it happens regardless of the client network, system or server. I've tried on 4 different networks, 4 different computers and ranging from home connection to a corporate connection. I've tried with a variety of dedicated and VPS providers in different data centers.

Comment: I think it's time to examine a network trace in the Chrome debugger network tab.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use WebSocket with NodeJS or Socket.io but experienced the same behaviour with Jetty. It turns out that Jetty has an idle timeout default to 5 minutes (or 300 seconds) for all WebSocket's sessions. You could change the default idle timeout value to an appropriate value or ping/pong those connections before it timed out.

In my situation, I decided to use ping/pong as it also helps determine when the connection is no longer there. I observed that in some cases, connection was not closed even when the network is down.

According to engine.io (which is used by [socket.io](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/)) [docs](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io#methods-1), the server seems to have default `pingInterval` of 25 seconds. So unless you inadvertently disabled or changed default options, the ping/pong mechanism should be in place.